# Is there any way of changing the font size of the tabs in Chromium?

Tags: 10.10, chromium

Is the a way of changing the font size of the tabs in Chromium?

Chromium 8.0.552.237 (70801)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, **no**. The font size is [[image] hardcoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coded) in the Chromium source code. This issue has been reported [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17866), you can "star" it to be notified of any changes.

Comment: hi there! Your link doesn't work, would you repost? I'am trying to find out about progress to that issue. thx, p.

Comment: @piedro The link works fine for me.

Comment: sry, you are right, this time it does for me also ... thx abyways ... seems over there nobody really interested in working on that ... sad!

Comment: OK, we have chromium 18 (!) now and this issue is still the same ... I don't know how nmany post I wrote on this and how many bug reoprts I commented within the last years ... it's a shame, I'd love to use chrome or chromium but I just can't read the tabs fonts - it's a total no go for me - sad!

Comment: chromium 21 - no change. The most annoying is that every time I post a bug report it's said that there is still this 5-year old bug (!!) and it's still open that's why you cannot write a new bug report without being closed immediatly. And I think the bug organising moderators are dillusional if they really think anyone will ever pick up to work for a 5 year old bug.

Comment: how hard can it be for them to just increase the font by 1 PIXEL! let's push them.

Comment: @DoR Was this ever resolved? I'm having the opposite issue, large cumbersome text in the tabs and omnibar. Why is everyone else seeing small text?

Comment: There is another issue on the Chromium bug tracker that appears to be getting more attention: [Issue 143619: No HiDPI support on Linux](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143619)