# Increase tab font size in chromium?

Tags: chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way of changing the font size of the tabs in Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23078/is-there-any-way-of-changing-the-font-size-of-the-tabs-in-chromium)

Is there any way to do this ? The font is insanely poor and small.

Attached screenshot:

[image]

I'm using 1920 x 1080 as native screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

[There is no way of doing this at the moment](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17866). Sorry.

Comment: Ok, I'll stick with firefox untill Chrome make this possible. Thanks.